# JavaFX progressBar different color of portions of progressBar

Tags: css, javafx

Is it possible to style javaFx's progressBar to have different color on portions of the progressbar. I tried setting the bar color to gradient. It is gradient, but when i lower the percentage, the color moves with the progress bar. I want to create progress bar style similar to this picture: [image: vu-meter]

This is the style i tried:

```
.progress-bar .bar {
    -fx-background-color: 
        linear-gradient(to right,#689F38 0%, #689F38 70%, #FBC02D 85%,  #d32f2f 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a little trick. In basic css there is a color-function called 'linear-gradient'. Basically it creates a gradient, but also allows color stops. Between color stops a gradient is applied.

So imagine the following bit style rule

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, green 60%, yellow 80&, red 100%);
```

This will result in something that looks like:
[image: normal linear gradient]

But if you add an extra stop with the same color at the start and end of the range, you'll end up with an hard edge. This is because you trick the system in changing the colors at the same position, while the actual spaces between edges contains the same color at the low and high end. e.g:

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, green 60%, yellow 60%, yellow 80%, red 80%, red 100%);
```

This will result in the desired effect:
[image: full-stops linear gradient]

As a sidenote, we dont have to define the start of the first color (green in this case), and the end of the last color (red in this case). This is because the css will automatically assume the color fills the rest of the space. So to complete rule can be shortened down to:

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, green 60%, yellow 60%, yellow 80%, red 80%);
```

Comment: Maybe i explained my problem badly. I dont have problem with the styling of the sliding portion of the progressbar. My problem is, when the progress of the progressbar changes, the style moves with the bar. Maybe example would be better. When the progressbar is at 100% you can see all the colors on it, but this does not change even when the bar is at 50%. You can still see the red part, which i dont want.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is a problem you can't solve that easily with the default progressbar. You could make your own implementation, and use a clip for the bar part. One sad part about it is that a clip is not part of the hiearchy in javafx. Therefore additional styling using css wil not be possible. So you have to hardcode the final shape of the bar...